Docker Actions Ignore the Installed Dependencies That Are Installed During the Build Step
I've created a Python GitHub action. It runs as a Docker container. One of its layers is the installation of some packages using uv. When I use that action from another repository, although it shows the dependencies are installed in the building step, it seems none of its dependencies are installed when it tries to use that action.
Action
Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-slim

# Installing uv
COPY --from=ghcr.io/astral-sh/uv:0.5.1 /uv /uvx /bin/

WORKDIR /action

COPY . .

# Installing the dependencies (it works)
RUN uv sync --no-install-project --no-cache

CMD [ "uv", "run", "/action/main.py" ]

The Python file (/action/main.py):
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["pip", "list"])

import requests
...

Action Usage
Here is the pipeline that I'm using from a different repository.
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    name: Running the action
    steps:

      - name: Using the action
        id: my_action
        uses: me/my-action@main
        with:
          url: "https://google.com"

      - name: Echo result
        run: echo ${{steps.my_action.outputs.status_code}}

Here is the error that I'm getting by running this pipeline:

I don't know what "Build me/my-action@main" step is, but in that step, the RUN uv sync --no-install-project --no-cache is executed successfully and all the requirements are installed in there, but in the "Using the action" step, there is nothing installed but pip.

I just double checked on my environment and RUN uv sync --no-install-project --no-cache do not install dependencies.
Seems --no-install-project flag is preventing to install any dependencies.
You could use following command, just make sure requirements.txt exists and has correct data
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


Thank you. I'm storing my dependencies in the pyproject.toml and uv sync does install the dependencies but in a venv. When I try pip and requirements.txt it works. The only difference between pip and uv here is the fact that uv installs the dependencies inside a venv. One more thing though. Correct me if I'm wrong. The Build me/my-action actually builds the image and then runs that image in a container with all the input variables (environment vars) in the Using the action step?!

I'm actually using uv due to its awesome performance compared to pip.

I have no issue with uv or any other way you install dependencies, but again I double checked and this RUN uv sync --no-install-project --no-cache will not install dependencies. I have no experience to troubleshoot farther what to do with uv.
